# WooCommerce: How to add hook for only one product? By ID?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a drop down list with quantity selection for only one item.

I'm using this code, but it turns on the dropdown on all products.

How can I use this script for only one product?

```
<?php
function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
global $product;
 
$defaults = array(
'input_name' => 'quantity',
'input_value' => '1',
'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
'step' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
'style' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
);
if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
$min = $defaults['min_value'];
else $min = 1;
 
if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
$max = $defaults['max_value'];
else $max = 20;
 
if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
$step = $defaults['step'];
else $step = 1;
 
$options = '';
for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
$options .= '<option value="' . $count . '">' . $count . '</option>';
}
echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything with an if statement where you check against ID that you have chosen.

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input() {
    global $product;
    if($product->get_id() === 14) :

    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This partially works, but the inputs on all other products disappear

Comment: Whoops, wrap only the code related to the dropdown (last part)

Comment: Can you please show me. On my example